# C# WPF OR logical gate between ValidationRules

Tags: c#, wpf, multidatatrigger

I'm using a combobox with validation and a save button as follows:

```
<ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" 
            x:Name="cmbGenerationTariff" IsEnabled="False" >
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Path="..." UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <common:ValidationRuleStringAnyLength  ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
</ComboBox>

...

<Button x:Name="btnSaveSite" Click="btnSave_Click"  Content="SAVE">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>                           
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbGenerationTariff, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbTimeZone, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />                         
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtCity, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbCountry, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

And it works just fine. The save button is enabled iff all elements are valid.

What I want is for the save button to be enabled also when elements are disabled (in other words, I don't need to validate the values of disabled elements).

How can I do it? can I maybe use an 'OR' condition (*element is valid OR element is disabled*)?

Comment: What is `ValidationRuleStringAnyLength`? Something of your own? Can you change that to make it check on disabled too?

Comment: Perhaps you can pass in the element to a property of your `ValidationRuleStringAnyLength` rule and test whether it is enabled? Something like `<common:ValidationRuleStringAnyLength Element="..."`

Comment: @MikeEason That's what I'll probably do if don't find a nicer way. I just thought I must have a way to check an *OR* between conditions in xaml...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Adi Lester put it, you'd probably be better off using [MVVM pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) here.
Consider adding e.g. [MVVMLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) as dependency, via NuGet, to get started easier.

If you do, you'll have that much better control over your logic. Consider simple Window `XAML`

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <!--Bind to Text and IsEnabled properties in ViewModel-->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
    </TextBox>
    <!--Bind to IsEnabled property in ViewModel-->
    <CheckBox Content="Text input enabled" 
              IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}">
    </CheckBox>
    <!--Bind to SaveCommand in ViewModel-->
    <Button Content="Save" 
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Where `MainWindow` codebehind is left as-is and `MainViewModel` (the DataContext) is

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase // <- MVVMLight ViewModel base class
{
    private string _text = null;
    private bool _isEnabled = true;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(
            // Execute command
            () => Console.WriteLine(@"Save command received, input value:{0}", Text),
            // Can execute command?
            () => !IsEnabled || (IsEnabled && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text)));
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set { _isEnabled = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Tadah! Now you have logic that toggles your `Save` button `on` when either text is entered or checkbox is left unchecked. And as additional bonus you are now officially Doing It Right ;)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you're using MVVM, but the correct thing to do would be to use a command for your button and have the `CanExecute` logic in your viewmodel. There you should be able to access the state of your data and perform more complex validation logic.

Comment: I think you could include some sort of minimal example on how to do this.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen These are the basics of MVVM. Hundreds of examples exist online.

Comment: Obviously the OP does not know the basics (or knows basics but not all of them), therefore supplying a clean example and explaining what you are doing is ideal as @MikkoViitala just provided within his answer.